# accepting parameters and raising an error

Tags: t-sql

I need to accept the parameters for ProductID and DiscountPercent, and raise an error if the value for DiscountPercent, but when I check the code it does not raise an error when I input a negative number, I have a feeling my pass through parameters is the problem because my raiserror works alone

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spUpdateProductDiscount') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
GO

CREATE PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
(@ProductID INT,
@DiscountPercent INT)
AS
begin
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update Products set DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent
WHERE ProductID = ProductID;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF @DiscountPercent < 0 
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR(N'The value for DiscountPercent must be positive',16,1)
 RETURN
END
END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you believe `CATCH` block code will always be executed. This is not the case. Only if there is an error in the `TRY` block execution is passed into the `CATCH` block.

Therefore, to fix your problem you need to move the `IF @DiscountPercent < 0 BEGIN... END` test to the `TRY` block, before the transaction with the `UPDATE` statement is opened. You'd then need to add an additional `RAISERROR` statement in the `CATCH` block that would elevate the error. Alternatively a `SELECT`/`PRINT` that would just display it instead. See any of the examples on [Technet's article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) on the subject.

You'd probably do well on handling unclosed transactions better. You see, if that `UPDATE` statement fails and control is passed over to the `CATCH` block, the transaction remains opened. You can inspect the page linked above for examples on this as well.

Comment: @ckuhn203, _SQL Server_ supports `GOTO`. You can use that the leave the `CATCH` block and pass the execution to, say `FINALLY:`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What would be wrong with writing it as follows?;

```
CREATE PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
(   
    @ProductID INT,
    @DiscountPercent INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @DiscountPercent < 0 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(N'The value for DiscountPercent must be positive',16,1)
    END

    UPDATE Products 
    SET DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;

END
GO
```

PS. `RAISERROR`, `GOTO` and `FINALLY` are deprecated AFAIK. It is advisable to use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`. Perhaps someone can correct me here?

Comment: There is no `FINALLY` construct in _SQL Server_ and technically neither `GOTO` nor `RAISERROR` are listed on [2012 deprecated features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), despite _Microsoft_ advising against using those in new applications. Fully agree on using `THROW` instead, though.

Comment: @barthazar - thanks, I'm not sure why I was under the impression that `GOTO` was deprecated. I've purposefully not familiarised myself with it because I believed it was EOL.